# Что можно сделать чтобы все антивирусы видели в моем файле вирус?

Tags: python, python-3.x, вирусы, антивирус

Я сделал вирус на python который исключительно для тестирования на проникновение но я не хочу чтобы мой вирус использовали во зло, что можно сделать чтоб мой вирус обнаруживали все антивирусы?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вставьте в текст программы [eicar code](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR-Test-File)

```
 "X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*"
```

Comment: Не факт, что поможет для всех антивирусов. Антивирусы имеют право игнорировать его, если файл длиннее 128 байт, и не начинается с этой последовательности.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте зловредный код - очевидно же.

Comment: там и так зловредный код но вирус тотал показал что лишь 39 антивирусов из 80 видят мой вирус

Comment: Sheud_z тогда проблема в самих антивирусах. Не каждый антивирус способен распознать вирус. Например тот-же винлокер они редко замечают.

Comment: Чушь, нельзя просто взять и засунуть все WinLocker-ы в одну категорию. WinLocker-ы созданные через билдеры легко распознаются 45+ анти-вирусами, кастомные же ну может +- 25-35, зашифрованные публичными крипторами ну может 20-30, а если и локер кастомный и криптовальщик приватный то тогда максимум 15.